# How to define a transitive relation in graql

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

my model consists of organizations that have projects and the projects have buckets. The buckets can be shared to other projects in the same organization. I defined a rule for project sharing which means that two projects are in this relation when first is sharing a bucket with the other.

```
    define

    organization sub entity,
        plays organizationRole,
        key identifier;

    project sub entity,
        plays projectRole,
        plays projectSourceRole, 
        plays projectTargetRole,
        plays transitiveProjectSourceRole,
        plays transitiveProjectTargetRole,
        key identifier;

    bucket sub entity,
        plays bucketRole,
        plays sharedBucketSourceRole,
        plays sharedBucketTargetRole,
        key identifier;


    organizationToProject sub relation,
        relates organizationRole,
        relates projectRole;

    projectToBucket sub relation,
        relates projectRole,
        relates bucketRole;

    sharedBucket sub relation,
        relates sharedBucketSourceRole,
        relates sharedBucketTargetRole;

    projectSharing sub relation,
        relates projectSourceRole,
        relates projectTargetRole;

    project-sharing sub rule, 
      when { 
        (projectRole: $ps, bucketRole: $bs) isa projectToBucket; 
        (projectRole: $pt, bucketRole: $bt) isa projectToBucket;
        (sharedBucketSourceRole: $bs, sharedBucketTargetRole: $bt) isa sharedBucket;
        $ps != $pt;
      }, then { 
        (projectSourceRole: $ps, projectTargetRole: $pt) isa projectSharing; 
      };
```

It works fine.  (see [image])

But I want to define a rule for transitive relation (according to some ancestry example I found in the docs) so I added to the schema:

```
    transitiveProjectSharing sub relation,
        relates transitiveProjectSourceRole,
        relates transitiveProjectTargetRole;

    transitive-project-sharing sub rule,
      when {
        (projectSourceRole: $a, projectTargetRole: $b) isa projectSharing;
        (projectSourceRole: $b, projectTargetRole: $c) isa projectSharing; 
      }, then {
        (transitiveProjectSourceRole: $a, transitiveProjectTargetRole: $c) isa transitiveProjectSharing;
      };
```

It finds nothing (but there are several transitive ones, see [image])

Would anyone have a suggestion where is the mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got a hint from Grakn.ai Slack. The transitivity should be defined on the `projectSharing` role itself, additional `transitiveProjectSharing` is not necessary. So the definition should be:

```
transitive-project-sharing sub rule,
  when {
    (projectSourceRole: $a, projectTargetRole: $b) isa projectSharing;
    (projectSourceRole: $b, projectTargetRole: $c) isa projectSharing; 
  }, then {
    (projectSourceRole: $a, projectTargetRole: $c) isa projectSharing; 
  };
```

and the query works well:
[image]

Comment: Would like to add that when querying in any Client API, you can pass an 'infer' boolean that turns inference on or off. Setting it to on (it's on by default) allows you to grab all transitive relations. Setting it to off will grab only immediate (i.e. already inserted in the graph) relations. Each has its own use case.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight improvement over your awesomely elegant answer (thanks!!), you can also use subtyping to differentiate explicit relationships from inferred relationships:

```
indirectProjectSharing sub projectSharing;

transitive-project-sharing sub rule,
  when {
    (projectSourceRole: $a, projectTargetRole: $b) isa projectSharing;
    (projectSourceRole: $b, projectTargetRole: $c) isa projectSharing; 
  }, then {
    (projectSourceRole: $a, projectTargetRole: $c) isa indirectProjectSharing; 
  };
```

Since `indirectProjectSharing` is a subtype of `projectSharing`, the rule's condition will match both relations, and you'll be able to refer to either type in your own queries depending on the use case.